# How to resign custom first responder swift

Tags: xcode, swift, view, keyboard, picker

I am using Xcode 6 and Swift. I have some text fields, and I have assigned their `inputView` attributes to picker views I have instantiated as such `var examplePickerView : UIPickerView = UIPickerView()`

This has the effect of showing the picker view instead of the conventional keyboard(s) when the textField is pressed for editing. The problem is that `textField.resignFirstResponder()` does not resign the picker view the way it would with the conventional keyboards. I have tried assigning the picker view as the first responder attribute but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to call :

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

That will resign the pickerView.

Comment: I just tried on a project and it does.
Can you give more explanations then ? Maybe you have some specifics you did not give...

Comment: I have found the source of the problem to be something different. I put print statements in my tap and swipe gesture action functions and it is not recognizing any gestures!

Comment: Finally got around to taking care of this, my gesture recognizers were for some reason set as delegates for a random view. Once I fixed this, self.view.endEditing(true) worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in where you resign the first responder. Also, I believe there's no need for you to set the text field as the first responder since it becomes the first responder when you tap on it to edit.

Answer (score 0):

you must use protocol UITextFieldDelegate

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
var textField : UITextField!

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width - 100, height: 50))
    textField.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(textField)

}
```